# WooCommerce how to send completed order emails to custom field email address

Tags: woocommerce

Within WooCommerce I created a custom field for a email address. Now I need WooCommerce to send completed order emails only to that custom field address if there is a value in that field.

I figured out how to send the completed order email to a custom email adres as BCC but now I'm trying to have the emails send to a custom field email adres without the standard email address.

Custom field email as BCC (working code):

//* Send invoice to accounts payable on completed orders *//

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 
'wcmos_email_cc_alternative', 10, 3);

function wcmos_email_cc_alternative( $recipient, $email_id, $order ) 
{
if ($email_id == 'customer_completed_order') {
    $alternative_email = $order->get_meta( 'purchase_order_email', 
true );
    if ( $alternative_email ) {

        $recipient = '$alternative_email';
    }
    }
return $recipient;
}
```

Custom field email as main reciepient (failing code):

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 
'wcmos_email_cc_alternative', 10, 3);

function wcmos_email_cc_alternative( $recipient, $email_id, $item_id 
) {
if ($email_id == 'customer_completed_order') {
    $alternative_email = $order->get_meta( 'purchase_order_email', 
true );
    $po_email = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 
'purchase_order_email - '.$enroll_num, true );
    if ( $alternative_email ) {

        $recipient = ', $po_email';

    }
}
return $recipient;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order filter takes two parameters: $recipients and $order

Seems like this is what you want:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'wcmos_email_cc_alternative', 10, 2);

function wcmos_email_cc_alternative( $recipient, $order) {
    $alternative_email = $order->get_meta('purchase_order_email',true);

    if ($alternative_email != '') {
        $recipient = $alternative_email;
    }

    return $recipient;
}
```

Comment: Suggest you use `$order->get_id()`. Directly accessing CRUD properties has been deprecated since WooCommerce 3.0. But I think the ideal would `$order->get_meta( 'purchase_order_email', true );`

Comment: @helgatheviking thanks for the suggestion. updated my answer

Comment: @Mos glad I could help.